# Formatting issue with multiple methods and making variables relevant

Tags: java, loops, format, output, ascii

Essentially my main issues comes from the last two methods in my program, drawBlock and drawTiers. It's designed to output the image of a cake and while it does, it doesn't do it in the way it's meant to. For instance, the program only allows odd input between 3 and 9 (3,5,7,9) and it uses these to decide how big of a cake to print. An input of 3 should get us

```
              *
              |
              |
          =========
          |..xxx..|
/^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\ 
[|_______||_______||_______|] 
[|___||_______||_______|___|] 
\===========================/
```

While a 5 would get us

```
                       *
                       |
                       |
                   =========
                   |..xxx..|
                   |..xxx..|
          |........xxxxxxxxx........|
          |........xxxxxxxxx........|
/^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\ 
[|_______||_______||_______||_______||_______|] 
[|___||_______||_______||_______||_______|___|] 
[|_______||_______||_______||_______||_______|] 
[|___||_______||_______||_______||_______|___|] 
\=============================================/
```

respectively. drawTiers has one int argument while drawBlock has two. Tiers is what's meant to decide how wide the tiers are as each time it calls drawBlock it's suppose to make the second argument larger, thus making tiers wider. Thing is while my program include a tier value, it doesn't do anything as it's ignored since I coded for each possible scenario. This isn't how it's meant to be done and I'm wondering how to get it to use the tiers value properly. Sorry If I didn't explain properly but I'd appreciate any help. Also "sizeParam" is just what the user input is sent down into the method as.

```
public static void drawBlock (int sizeParam, int tierParam) {
        if (sizeParam == 3) {
            System.out.printf("%20s", "|..xxx..|\n");
        }
        else if (sizeParam == 5) {
            for (int count = 0; count < sizeParam/2; count++) {
                System.out.printf("%29s", "|..xxx..|\n");
            }
            for (int count = 0; count < sizeParam/2; count++) {
                System.out.printf("%38s", "|........xxxxxxxxx........|\n");
            }
        }
        else if (sizeParam == 7) {
            for (int count = 0; count < sizeParam/2; count++) {
                System.out.printf("%38s", "|..xxx..|\n");
            }
            for (int count = 0; count < sizeParam/2; count++) {
                System.out.printf("%47s", "|........xxxxxxxxx........|\n");
            }
            for (int count = 0; count < sizeParam/2; count++) {
                System.out.printf("%56s", "|..............xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..............|\n");
            }
        }
        else if (sizeParam == 9) {
            for (int count = 0; count < sizeParam/2; count++) {
                System.out.printf("%47s", "|..xxx..|\n");
            }
            for (int count = 0; count < sizeParam/2; count++) {
                System.out.printf("%56s", "|........xxxxxxxxx........|\n");
            }
            for (int count = 0; count < sizeParam/2; count++) {
                System.out.printf("%65s", "|..............xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..............|\n");
            }
            for (int count = 0; count < sizeParam/2; count++) {
                System.out.printf("%74s", "|....................xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....................|\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void drawTiers (int tiersParam) {
        for (int count = 0; count <= tiersParam/10; count++) {
            int size = tiersParam;
            drawBlock(size, tiersParam + 1);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to print characters instead of full lines. With that you can manipulate what needs to be printed per tier, based on size parameter.

Here is an attempt on the same. You may need to tweak some numbers based on your exact output requirements

```
public static void drawTiersNew (int tiersParam) {
    for (int level = 0; level < tiersParam/2 ; level++) {
        drawBlockNew(level, tiersParam/2);
    }
}

public static void drawBlockNew (int level, int tierParam) {
   for (int repeat = 1; repeat <= tierParam; repeat++) {
        for (int count = 0; count < (tierParam - level)*9 ; count++) {
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.print('|');
        for (int count = 0; count < (2 + 6 * level) ; count++) {
            System.out.print('.');
        }
        for (int count = 0; count < (3 + 6 * level); count++) {
            System.out.print('x');
        }
        for (int count = 0; count < (2 + 6 * level); count++) {
            System.out.print('.');
        }
        System.out.print('|');
        System.out.print('\n');
    }
}
```

And here is what it prints for *drawTiersNew(9)*

```
                                    |..xxx..|
                                    |..xxx..|
                                    |..xxx..|
                                    |..xxx..|
                           |........xxxxxxxxx........|
                           |........xxxxxxxxx........|
                           |........xxxxxxxxx........|
                           |........xxxxxxxxx........|
                  |..............xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..............|
                  |..............xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..............|
                  |..............xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..............|
                  |..............xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..............|
         |....................xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....................|
         |....................xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....................|
         |....................xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....................|
         |....................xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....................|
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it could be solved with a for loop but didn't know how to get it to send the bottom one just once and have it do the calculations/printing all together. I never thought of subtracting the parameter from the original input variable either to get the correct spaces. I'll keep this in mind for future codes though, thank you once again.